# Google Sheets Split Column into multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula

There's this formula that seems to work in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63531300/splitting-single-column-into-multiple-columns-1000-rows-per-column):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(COUNTA(A2:A)/3),3,ROW(A2))),{ROW(A2:A),A2:A},2,0))
```

but when I try to use it for a range of 26 cells in a single column(K3:K28) to split it every 6 cells, using this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(COUNTA(K3:K28)/6);6;ROW(K3)));{ROW(K3:K28);K3:K28};2;0))
```

it gives the error: VLOOKUP evaluates to an out-of-bounds range.

How to fix it??

Comment: The mentioned formula is bound to rows. Please share a test sheet so you can be easier helped.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Formula is working for me. Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you're working on?

Comment: @lamblichus It could be a locale issue.

Comment: @marikamitsos Yeah I noticed. I think that's the case. I posted an answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking the problem is due to different syntaxes the different locales use. If you're using a locale that uses `;` (e.g. Germany), the separator here:

```
{ROW(K3:K28);K3:K28}
```

Should be `\` instead:

```
{ROW(K3:K28)\K3:K28}
```

So your formula should be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(COUNTA(K3:K28)/6);6;ROW(K3)));{ROW(K3:K28)\K3:K28};2;0))
```

I would also use [IFNA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944?hl=en) since 26 is not divisible by 6, so the last column will be incomplete:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(COUNTA(K3:K28)/6);6;ROW(K3)));{ROW(K3:K28)\K3:K28};2;0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Since the OP does not provide a test sheet or any visual data iI think it would be easier to others if you were to show an image of the working formula. Just a thought.

Comment: Thank you, you nailed the problem. I was aware that , becomes ; with some Locales but didn't know that \ also changes. Thanks, also, for improve the formula.